# ¿Por qué mi codigo no imprime el último valor?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con mi código: básicamente este calcula el salario de un trabajador administrativo u operativo, esto en base al input, si es *1* es administrativo y se le descuenta el 12% y lo correspondiente con el operativo con un 17% de descuento.

Mi input recibe múltiples entradas, en la cual *a* y *b* representan el sueldo neto y si es administrativo u operativo, respectivamente. Al momento de imprimir, imprime todos los resultados, excepto aquel producido por el último input, hasta que le doy enter y recién sale.

Ejemplo de entrada:

```
3500 2
2700 1
3200 2
3517 1
3846 2
3761 1
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
2905.0
2376.0
2656.0
3094.96
3192.18
3309.68 #(Este último recien sale, cuando doy enter durante la ejecución de código)
```

```
import sys
leer = 0

for leer in (sys.stdin):
    a,b=map(int,leer.split())

    if b==1:
        salario = round(float(a) - (float(a*12/100)),2)

    elif b==2:
        salario = round(float(a) - (a*17/100),2)

    print(salario)
```

Comment: Para leer del teclado se usa `input()`.

Comment: La entrada estándar es buffereada por líneas. Esto significa que hasta que no has escrito una línea completa (y pulsado el retorno de carro), el contenido de esa línea no se le pasa a tu programa. Esto es conveniente porque da la oportunidad al usuario de editar lo escrito (por si se equivoca) y sólo cuando pulse ENTER se enviará al programa.

Answer (score 0):

Se usa `input()` para leer del teclado, lo que te devuelve una línea completa cuando el usuario da ENTER.

Para este tipo de trabajo, el patrón es usar un `while True` y adentro colocar la condición de salida, para escapar con un `break`.

Corregido ese detalle, este es el código correcto. Sólo falta que le agregues la condición de salida.

```
while True:
    leer = input("Ingrese salario y tipo: ")
    if condición_de_salida:
         break

    a, b = map(int,leer.split())

    if b==1:
        salario = round(float(a) - (float(a*12/100)),2)
    elif b==2:
        salario = round(float(a) - (a*17/100),2)

    print(salario)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo que pasa es que me piden que ingrese la entrada separada de un espacio, ejemplo 5000 1 (Sueldo, tipo de trabajador) y que se realice el número de iteraciones en función al primer número, algo como esto.

2 ----> número de iteraciones
5000 1 -----> Sueldo y tipo de trabajador.
4500 2 -----> Sueldo y tipo de trabajador.